# UILabel getting blured?

Tags: ios, ios5, uilabel, carousel, icarousel

I am new in iOS development,
I am created custom carousel view in iOS. All views in carrousel are rotate in 360,
But I have problem when I added UILabel on front View then it gets blurred..

I read from somewhere frame may be set as in float and use [lbl setFrame:CGRectIntegral(lbl.frame)]; 
but I have tried this,This type is not in my case.

Why this is happening ?

Plz help me...

Thank you..

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I think you'll need another upvote to get the ability to attach photos though.

Answer (score -1):

I think, your `UILabel` is obscured by other views. Try `[myView bringSubviewToFront:myLabel]`. Good Luck!